# Cell complex of a torus confusion

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I'm trying to understand the CW complex of the standard Torus and I'm getting kinda confused. In my notes my professor constructed it as the representation given by
$$<a,b \,\vert \,aba^{-1}b^{-1}>$$
[or as in here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FBuilding-the-torus-as-a-CW-complex-n-cell-by-n-cell_fig15_307636470&psig=AOvVaw3LVWpF_mwsAqlPOx_zIKkB&ust=1634105755824000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAgQjRxqFwoTCJC6mLucxPMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAO)

That is we start off with a 0-cell then attach two 1-cell to it, followed up with attaching the sides of a rectangle with the corresponding orientation (opposite edges get identified with their "antipodal" point. But looking at hatcher and munkres they construct the torus by attaching points opposite on parallel edges together i.e.
$$<a,b\,\vert \,abab>$$
The latter one makes the most sense to me and is how I'd imagine creating a torus from a piece of paper. Given [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F3418311%2Fcw-complex-structure-and-intuitive-construction-of-spaces&psig=AOvVaw3LVWpF_mwsAqlPOx_zIKkB&ust=1634105755824000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAgQjRxqFwoTCJC6mLucxPMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAT).
What's the difference between the two construction? Or is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically, the pictures for both cases you provide are correct and are the same.

However, $abab$ would mean that while you traverse the boundary of the square, $a$ and $b$ are pointing towards the direction of your movement both times you meet them. This is not the case: starting from the lower left corner and moving clockwise, we go first along $a$ and $b$, but then meet $a$ pointing backwards relative to our movement. So $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is the correct way to write it.

Comment: ahhh I see. I was able to convince myself $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ also give the torus by folding paper but wasn't sure if it was the same topologically as $abab$ but I supposed looking at open sets around edges, it would be.

Comment: @asuuuka just in case: it's not "also": $abab$ is the projective plane.

Comment: actually to clear confusion. In $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is the bottom left corner still glued to the bottom right corner? and top left corner to top right? Or is that $abab$?

Comment: @asuuuka In both cases all corners glue into one point.

Comment: sorry maybe I should've have phrased it better. If the square is given by [0,1]x[0,1] would the point on the edge [0,1/4] get glued to [1,1/4]? I supposed a,b specifies the orientation the edges get glued onto the one cell?

Comment: @asuuuka on the torus yes, of course. For $abab$ it will be $1/4$ to $3/4.$ You supposed right, yes.